# passing 2 arguments to a function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

In Haskell, I know that if I define a function like this `add x y = x + y`
then I call like this `add e1 e2`. that call is equivalent to `(add e1) e2`
which means that applying `add` to one argument `e1` yields a new function which is then applied to the second argument `e2`.

That's what I don't understand in Haskell. in other languages (like Dart), to do the task above, I would do this

```
add(x) {
  return (y) => x + y;
}
```

I have to explicitly `return` a function. So does the part "yields a new function which is then applied to the second argument" automatically do underlying in Haskell? If so, what does that "hiding" function look like? Or I just missunderstand Haskell?

Answer (score 10):

In Haskell, everything is a value,

```
add x y = x + y
```

is just a syntactic sugar of:

```
add = \x -> \y -> x + y
```

For more information: https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying :

> In Haskell, all functions are considered curried: That is, all functions > in Haskell take just single arguments.
>
> This is mostly hidden in notation, and so may not be apparent to a new
>   Haskeller. Let's take the function
>
> `div :: Int -> Int -> Int`
>
> which performs integer division. The expression div 11 2
>   unsurprisingly evaluates to 5. But there's more that's going on than
>   immediately meets the untrained eye. It's a two-part process. First,
>
> `div 11`
>
> is evaluated and returns a function of type
>
> `Int -> Int`
>
> Then that resulting function is applied to the value 2, and yields 5.
>   You'll notice that the notation for types reflects this: you can read
>
> `Int -> Int -> Int`
>
> incorrectly as "takes two Ints and returns an Int", but what it's
>   really saying is "takes an Int and returns something of the type Int
>   -> Int" -- that is, it returns a function that takes an Int and returns an Int. (One can write the type as Int x Int -> Int if you
>   really mean the former -- but since all functions in Haskell are
>   curried, that's not legal Haskell. Alternatively, using tuples, you
>   can write (Int, Int) -> Int, but keep in mind that the tuple
>   constructor (,) itself can be curried.)

Comment: How does the returned function know about `11`? Does it store `11` in its memory & then take `2` as arguments of it.

Comment: The returned function is a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) that captures the 11 at the time of its creation, care of [lexical scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping).

Comment: Note also that one of the most basic optimizations GHC does is not bothering to make an intermediate closure if it's going to be used only for immediate application to a known argument.